# Java Creating a Table with Columns in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'm extremely new to MySQL and was curious how I can go along with creating a table in MySQL with the desired columns I'd like if **it does not already exist** using **Java**.

[image: Visual of what I'd like]

Comment: Start with [JDBC Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) and [CREATE TABLE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)

Answer (score 0):

The following code is written to do exactly what you want. You have to use JDBC mySQL driver to connect to a mySQL server through java. Hope this helps.

```
//assuming that you are using JDBC connector for mysql
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

//connect to mysql server. We are using a class in the imported java mysql library to establish a connection with the mysql database server
//root is the username, next parameter is the password.
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/?", "root", "");

//ceeate a statement to be executed in the mysql database server.
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

//create database if it doesn't exist
//That is, sending a create table mysql command to the database server.
statement.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS sheetdata");

//create table if it doesn't exist. This was a example I used. You can change the table definition as you want.
//this will send the create table sql statement to be executed in the mysql server
statement.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sheetdata.`saveddata` (\n"
        + "  `INDEX` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\n"
        + "  `FILENAME` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,\n"
        + "  `TABLENAME` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,\n"
        + "  `TIMESTAMP` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,\n"
        + "  PRIMARY KEY (`INDEX`)\n"
        + ") ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;");
connection.close();
```

Comment: Do you mind telling me what each line of the execute code does?

Comment: Added some more comments for you to understand. You better search and find more about java mysql connector library. It will help u understand more.

Comment: I understand what the execute stuff does, just why you put the stuff like "varchar" and "DEFAULT NULL"     Also, would I be able to use this execute command with something like HikariCP?

Comment: You implied that you are using mysql (as a tag in this question). Therefore you should be knowing that "varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL" is a mysql syntax of specifying the data type of a column and the default value of that column (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-create-tables.htm). And you can use HikarCP instead of commonly used java mysql connector by apache. https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP follow this link and see how to initialize connection there.